# How does TFS (2015) manages eventual merge conflict?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

We're many teams of developers working on (the same) few branches on TFS. We will be merging from branche to branche (Main to Release).

I'm curious about knowing how does TFS will be managing eventual conflict if two or more developers are merging the same thing (changes impacting the same files or script) at the same time?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: To make it more clear, if there is a chance that two or more developers will be merging int the very exact same time, how does TFS will know/manage/handel which person will need to resolve eventual conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

if a merge conflict arises, someone needs to intervene and consolidate the conflict, it is not done automatically.

It's automatically merged only when there is no conflict (at least no conflict as far as TFS can tell)

more information here: https://www.visualstudio.com/it-it/docs/tfvc/resolve-team-foundation-version-control-conflicts

> To make it more clear, if there is a chance that two or more developers will be merging int the very exact same time, how does TFS will know/manage/handel which person will need to resolve eventual conflicts?

Conflicts are to be resolved by the person checking in, on attempting to check-in, if new conflicts occur then they must be resolved.  Note resolving of conflicts is a *local* change, not source change.  Once conflicts are resolved, and attempted to be checked in, if more arise, they will need to be resolved as well.

you're on a team of 1k developers?  Have you been checking in as you go?  Into the same branch? into different branches?  I would assume you would have to have the work split up pretty well to not be stepping on toes, but it's really hard to say for sure.  TFS is good about merges, as long as the code is manageable.

Comment: so do you think there will always be at least someone merging who'll need to intervene ?

Comment: if your code is organized well, with a separation of concerns, and loose coupling, merge conflicts should be minimal.  I've generally only worked on smaller teams, but everything is auto resolved more often than not (at least on the code i've worked on).  The only real exception to that is one project had a 38k line WCF service, which would generally always have conflicts.  Had the code been more logically separated out, be it through a different service, or partial class files, merge conflicts would occur less often.

Comment: We're more than 1k person working on a very big project, and in a hurry we will be all merging everything we have in next two days...